# Delphi XE7 Audit Error 'Array index is out of range'

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe7

Delphi XE7 Audit shows me an error 'Array index is out of range' here:

```
for i := 0 to High(Hazards) do begin
  if Hazards[i].Ident = 123 then begin
    HazardId := i;
    Break;
  end;
end;
```

What is the problem?

Hazards is a dynamic array

Comment: @MartynA, compiler translates `High(dynarr)` to `Lenght(dynarr) - 1`, it's a bit *hairy* to have `0` instead of `Low` but it have no effect.

Comment: Show reproducible complete code, please (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `i` is a signed type and that `Hazards` is a dynamic array, then the code is correct and the audit is wrong. An array has bounds `low()` to `high()` and the former is always zero for a dynamic array.

If my assumptions are valid then you should submit a bug report. I am not prepared to claim a bug with total certainty since you did not show a complete reproduction.